# Xtext strip quotes from string but remain having whitespaces in between words

Tags: string, grammar, xtext, xtend

I'm working on Xtext project and I want to have a grammar that would allow me to:
1. String quotes from strings, ex: "string" -> string
2. Allow to consider a string chunks separated with spaces as one string.

I would like to have a following concrete syntax:

```
fieldSet setname[

question what do you prefer to drink? [
  cola,
  coda water,
  apple juice
  ]
]
```

As you can see 'what do you prefer to drink' has to be considered as one string without quotes.
At the moment I made a custom terminal as well as converter. But it does not work as I want.

```
terminal QSTRING returns ecore::EString: //custom terminal SurveyString
     ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '?' | '!'| '@'| '#' | '%' | '^' |     '&' | '('|')'| '0'..'9'|' ')*;



FieldSet returns FieldSet:
'fieldSet' name=QSTRING
'['
question+=Question (',' question+=Question)*
']';

Question returns Question:
'question'
name=QSTRING
'[' has+=AnswerOption (',' has+=AnswerOption)*
(other?=('other'))?
']';

AnswerOption returns AnswerOption:
name=QSTRING;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your grammar inherits from common.Terminals? That grammar hides whitespace by default.

You can put `hidden()` behind your terminal rule's name to make sure that whitespace is not ignored inside it.